# Creating system mode mode (dark mode)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am going to design a dark mode for my wordpress theme.

I have no problem designing dark mode and light mode and I have easily designed these two.
But I'm looking to create a third mode which is the default for pages.

The third mode I want to create is the automatic use of dark mode or light mode using the user's default settings for their browser or system.

Something similar to the site (stackoverflow.com) that I have placed in the image below:

[image]

I don't know where to start to create such a state and all the code I wrote is as follows:

```js
let bodyMode = document.querySelector("#pageMode");
let SystemMode = document.querySelector(".SystemMode");
let DarkMode = document.querySelector(".DarkMode");
let LightMode = document.querySelector(".LightMode");

SystemMode.addEventListener("click", function () {

//I don't have any idea to create mod system mode

});

DarkMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyDark");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyHalfLit");
});

LightMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyDark");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyHalfLit");
});
```

```css
#pageMode {
  background: #eee;
}

.bodyDark {
  background: #000 !important;
}

.bodyHalfLit {
  background: #909090 !important;
}

.main-selectMode {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body id="pageMode">

    <div class="dropdown main-selectMode">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
            page Mode
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="SystemMode"><a class="dropdown-item">System Mode</a></li>
            <li class="LightMode"><a class="dropdown-item">Light Mode</a></li>
            <li class="DarkMode"><a class="dropdown-item">Dark Mode</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: I updated my answer assuming this as the way you wanted to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS You can use

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* Dark mode styles here */
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  /* Light mode styles here */
}
```

I maybe able to help you refine this to your use case if you require.

Let us say you want to use your current structure and continue with that you can do this.

```js
const isDarkMode = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

if(isDarkMode){
    $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyDark");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyHalfLit");
} else {
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyDark");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyHalfLit");
}
```

Comment: Hello. How do I add this to my scripts? If I put the same CSS in my code, will the problem be solved?

Comment: All you are supposed to do is add your different styles under these media queries.

Comment: let me edit my answer.

Comment: @php I have edited the answer I hope that helps.

Comment: Nvm my man! Awesome. Glad could help.